# play background music on page load on Safari

Tags: javascript, web, safari, cross-browser, mozilla

I want to play background music on page load.

My code runs fine on all browsers except Safari.

Safari shows.

```
Undefined is not constructor(evaluating new audio())
```

How can I fix this error on Safari?

```
var audio, playbtn, mutebtn, seek_bar;
function initAudioPlayer(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "html/audio/di-evantile_behind-your-dream.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
    // Set object references
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    // Add Event Handling
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);

    // Functions
    function playPause(){
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.play();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(html/images/pause.png) no-repeat";
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(html/images/play.png) no-repeat";
        }
    }

    function mute(){
        if(audio.muted){
            audio.muted = false;
            mutebtn.style.background = "url(html/images/speaker.png) no-repeat";
        } else {
            audio.muted = true;
            mutebtn.style.background = "url(html/images/speaker_muted.png) no-repeat";
        }
    }
}

//play music on page load
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

Comment: What version of Safari?

Comment: safari 5.1.7 windows 10 version

Comment: according to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) web audio API is not available in safari prior to version 6 - however the `<audio>` tag has been supported in safari since version 3.1 - perhaps you need to rethink how you add the audio if `Audio` constructor doesn't exist

Comment: any suggestions then?? just want play pause button for bakground music

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a strange comment in your JavaScript. I had to remove "## Heading ##" in order for your script to run on my machine.

Regarding Safari:

Safari for Windows was [discontinued](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/25/apple_kills_windows_pc_support_in_safari_60) back in 2012. I wouldn't be surprised if all sorts of HTML5 goodies didn't work in the Windows version.

**It's working for me on a Mac OSX system with Safari 9.1.1 (11601.6.17).**

I also tried using Safari for Windows as you described, and I can confirm that it doesn't work because the Audio object is not supported.

Comment: is this script running on your machine?

Comment: Yes, but I did have to remove "## HEADING ##" from your code. (I see that you've edited it since then.)

Comment: thanx a lot..!  plz check if bckground music stops on click

Comment: Note that it's running on my Mac OSX machine with Safari, not on my Windows machine. Safari for Windows doesn't support the Audio object and likely never will. It does run on my Windows system if I use Google Chrome instead of Safari for Windows.